# musicians always having face covered

Tags: hip-hop, appearance

The artist called 'Carla's Dreams' always appears on concerts wearing a hood, sunglasses, and having his face painted, in order to remain incognito. His true identity has remained unknown so far, although there are speculations.

I was just curious if he might have copied this feature from another artist, or it is an original thing indeed. Do you know any other singers that, in a similar fashion, keep their identity secret?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know of Buckethead (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckethead) and the band Ghost (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(Swedish_band)), but this guy may have never seen another incognito artist. A person just needs to not want to be recognized in order to start a career "dressing as a character" rather than presenting him/herself as he/she is, so, no need for influences to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Several artists have put on masks and face coverings as part of their acts, hoping to not be identified.  Masks and such can aid performance for specific artists because it can create a boundary between the artist and the audience where the artist feels safe to be as bold as they intend to be.  It is part of a tradition for artists to take on disguises when creating the art they want to make including nom de plumes, costumes, disguises and so on.

Some examples:

Deadmau5 (name is known)

marshmello (name is unknown)

Comment: Could you pls give some names ? for ex. David Bowie, Alex Harvey

Comment: Probably one of the most famous examples in musical history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_(band)